# Is it worth to separate one new asp.net 5 mvc 6 project into multiple ones?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to achieve modular architecture in a new asp.net 5 mvc 6 app. The idea is to somehow split one project into several business specific modules (mvc projects?) with separate controllers and views and other mvc project stuff.

Additionally, the solution would consist of Core, Framework and Tests class library projects.

My question are:

- How to achieve this kind of project separation?
- Can you give some other ideas how to achieve modular architecture in mvc 6?
  Do you think it's better (because of the overhead) to move to other architectures styles like N-tier, CQRS, Domain model, micro-services?

Comment: Why splitting the front part into several mvc projects ? can't you achieve this with mvc areas ?

Comment: I was playing with Orchard Framework which offers such solution - multiple mvc projects treated as modules that can be turn on / off. From programming model perspective it's quite nice - each developers is doing own project. Sadly I have no idea how to achieve this and is it worth. So I'm searching for good practices and working solutions.

Comment: You could use areas: http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html.